# MySQL inside for loop. Insert only runs on first loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I created a for loop that loops through an array or words exploded from a string. The for loop works and has been tested by echo statements. When running this code it only inserts 1 record into the database rather than the number of strings in the array.

```
$item=explode(" ", $items);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($item); ++$i) {
    // Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO invlog (itemid, qty)
VALUES ('".$item[$i]."', '-1')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);    
    }
```

Comment: sidenote: why not take out that connection outside before the loop. no need to connect/close every iteration

Comment: Are you getting an error message or does it seem to be failing silently?

Comment: Connecting and closing for each iteration like this is absurd.

Comment: no errors. also I have tried moving both the close and conn outside the for many times, still has the same issues

Comment: @chuckbeyor what does `$items` contain? you should post it in the question too. if one of those words are quoted, then your query will be screwed. you should bind them instead.

Comment: You should make a global page for your connection.

Comment: $items= 1234 4321 9876 6789

Answer (score 2):

For efficiancy, and to avoid multiple database calls, you should really only execute the statemnt once.

So loop through, create the query, then execute it.

Like so..

```
$item=explode(" ", $items);
$query="";
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($item); ++$i) {
  // Build Query 
  $query.="(".$item[$i].",-1),";
 }
 $query = rtrim($query); // Remove last trailing comma from the right hand side of query string

 //Connect to database, and do DB stuff outside of loop in one call
 $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 $sql = "INSERT INTO invlog (itemid, qty)
 VALUES ".$query;

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '4321 9876 6543,-1),'

Comment: trialling comma is still there

Comment: @chuckbeyor well if you look at that, it wasn't really exploded. `'4321 9876 6543,-1),'` the numbers are still joined with a space. you should put `var_dump($item)` in your question as well. and just use `rtrim($query, ',')` for that

Comment: This is the query it makes (itemid, qty)
 VALUES (1234 4321 9876 6543,-1)

Comment: I got a question. If these were submited in a text area and each one was on a new line might that be a issue?

Comment: @chuckbeyor yes of course, `<space>` and `\n line breaks` are different

Answer (score 0):

```
$replacer  = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r", "\t", "  ");
$items = str_replace($replacer, " ", $items);
$item=explode(" ", $items);
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


for ($i = 0; $i < count($item); ++$i) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO invlog (itemid, qty)
VALUES ('".$item[$i]."', '-1')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}


    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
```